# Geomesa-utils: How to choose ResolutionRange

Tags: java, geospatial, geohashing, geomesa

Using geomesa-utils to get geohashes, I shall pass as parameter ResolutionRange instance. See https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/4ef7662cd695008cfd6ed4ee4b4cb0bc45b886cc/geomesa-utils/src/main/scala/org/locationtech/geomesa/utils/geohash/GeohashUtils.scala#L60

I need to get 6 letters geohashes. After some tests, I found that the `maxBitsResolution` should be `nb letters` x 5 . So I set it to `30`.

What is the logic inside? How should I choose the `minBitsResolution` and `numBitsIncrement`?

Thx.

Comment: What method are you calling?

Comment: GeohashUtils.decomposeGeometry(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only 6-letter geohashes from `GeohashUtils.decomposeGeometry`, then you would pass in `ResolutionRange(30, 30, 0)`.

The `decomposeGeometry` method can return variable size geohashes. For example, decomposing the whole cartesian plane could be returned as 2 1-bit geohashes, 4 2-bit geohashes, etc. For irregular polygons, the interior of the polygon can generally be represented by a coarser geohash with no loss of precision, while finer geohashes can be used for the edge areas to minimize the extra, non-overlapping area. This is easier to understand in this [visualization](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geohash-substrings.html?highlight=geohash#the-algorithm) in the GeoMesa documentation.

The `ResolutionRange` argument defines the acceptable size of output geohashes, providing the minimum geohash resolution, the maximum resolution, and the step increment when going from one resolution to the next.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! However please note that a 0 step increment is not valide (at least 1), and min resolution should be less than max resolution. So I guess this is not possible to have everytime a geohash with the same size.

Comment: In that case, something like `ResolutionRange(0, 30, 30)` might work, as the initial zero-bit geohash wouldn't ever be used.